# How can I change the order of the boxes

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, foreach, dice

**The order of the numbers in my box is as follows:**
[image]

```
function boxNumbers(){
        let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
        boxes.forEach((box,i)=>{
        
            if(String(i).length==1 || (String(i).length==2 && Number(String(i)[0]))%2==0){
                //box.innerHTML = `${100-i}, i=${i}`
        
              box.innerHTML = 100-i 
            }
            else{
                box.innerHTML = String(Number(`${9-Number(String(i)[0])}${String(i)[1]}`)+ 1) 
        
              
            }
        })
        
        }
```

**how can I change it to look like this:**

[image]

Comment: There's actually way too much code, can you reduce your question to the relevants parts?

Comment: I wanted to show the code because I'm not quite sure where the problem may be.

Comment: But i think the problem is in those lines:                                                             
    function checarVictoria(){
    if(margenArriba()==-39 && margenIzquierdo()==0){
    document.querySelector('#p_turno').innerHTML = `${turno} ¡Player wins!`
    new Audio('win.mp3').play()
    return turno
}

else{
    return 'none'
}
}
check the range

function checarRango(dadoNum){
    let fueraDeRango = false
if(margenArriba()==-39.2 && (margenIzquierdo()+Number((dadoNum*-9.8).toFixed(1)))<0){
    fueraDeRango = true
}
return fueraDeRango
}

Comment: Then you need to debug more and narrow it down. We only have the vaguest description of what the problem actually is, and way too much code, which we'd even have to copy and paste together into a coherent snippet to run. We can't help you this way.

Answer (score 1):

The way the pawns are moving, I think probably your board is not setup properly?

Shouldn't it be something like this:

[image]

Comment: I try to change the order but i can't do it